Using CONCAT and SET variable in a single MYSQL Query on SELECT all
I have a MYSQL table called shoptable.
This table contains an article number in the column/field named sku.
I have an empty column/field called imgurl, which I would like a single query to populate for all rows.
I would like to concat a static string, containing the URL and the article number (sku) being the long tail path and UPDATE it into the imageurl field.
This query is out of my league.
To explain what I am trying to achieve, here a laymens attempt of writing it:
UPDATE shoptable AS s 
SET @IMGPATH = s.sku 
SET @URL = CONCAT("websitedomain.com/", IMGPATH) 
SET s.imageurl = URL

I am using double quotes as the query is called from inside NODE JS and is embedded in single quotes. I could change that around if needed.

I would recommend CONCAT_WS if  sku has null values . Which to use, concat, concat_ws? in mysql

If the relation between sku and imageurl is strict then you may use generated column. .. , imageurl TEXT AS (CONCAT("websitedomain.com/", sku)), ..

@ErgestBasha I think that when sku is NULL then imageurl should be NULL too and not 'websitedomain.com/'..

@Akina maybe. It is better that OP knows the difference between both, that was my intend.

You can use the following Query:
UPDATE shoptable SET imageurl = CONCAT("websitedomain.com/", sku);


Thanks so much. It looks really simple that way :)
